# Best free/commercial software for editing latex file on windows

Tags: windows

What are the best free or commercial software for editing `LaTeX` on Windows machine?

Comment: Do you mean what editor? This might be a duplicate of [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/82917).

Comment: There is no single "best" software, as it depends largely on the requirements.